# Insert with While/Foreach

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach, while-loop, sql-insert

I am desperately looking for a solution, but I can't find one.
I have this insert in my model

View:

```php
<?php echo form_open('setup/insert_step006'); ?>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Speichern</button>
<?php foreach ($view_old_auflage as $auflage): ?>
    <div class="input-group mb-3 input-group-sm">
        <input type="<?php echo $input; ?>" class="form-control" name="add_setup_000[<?php echo $auflage['auflage_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $auflage['auflage_id']; ?>">
        <input type="<?php echo $input; ?>" class="form-control" name="add_setup_001[<?php echo $auflage['auflage_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $auflage['auflage_name']; ?>">
        <?php foreach ($view_old_tcg as $tcg): ?>
            <input type="<?php echo $input; ?>" class="form-control" name="add_setup_00<?php echo $tcg['tcg_id'] + 1; ?>[<?php echo $auflage['auflage_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $auflage['auflage_' . $tcg['tcg_short'] . '']; ?>">
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
    </br>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Model:

```php
foreach ($this->input->post('add_setup_000') as $setup_000) {
    $this->db->like('tb_auflage_name', $this->input->post('add_setup_001')[$setup_000]);
    $result = $this->db->get('db_auflage');
    if ($result->num_rows() < 1) {
        $data = array(
            'tb_auflage_name' => $this->input->post('add_setup_001')[$setup_000],
            'tb_auflage_ygo' => $this->input->post('add_setup_002')[$setup_000],
            'tb_auflage_mtg' => $this->input->post('add_setup_003')[$setup_000],
            'tb_auflage_pkm' => $this->input->post('add_setup_004')[$setup_000],
        );
        $this->db->insert('db_auflage', $data);
    }
}
```

I want to put the part from "tb_auflage_ygo" in a loop, like in the view.
But I can't figure out how to do that.
Do you have a solution?

Comment: `I am desperately looking for a solution, but I can't find one` - to what problem?

Comment: You forgot to tell us specifically what the problem is. Therefore it's quite hard to suggest a solution...

Comment: How i can loop the part from "tb_rest_ygo" to "tb_rest_pkm".
Not that I have to change this manually every time.

Comment: I want to know how to loop the part with "tb_support_ygo".

Answer (score 0):

I prefer not to use the endforeach

```
<?php echo form_open('setup/insert_step006'); ?>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Speichern</button>
<?php foreach ($view_old_auflage as $auflage) { ?>
    <div class="input-group mb-3 input-group-sm">
        <input type="<?php echo $input; ?>" class="form-control" name="add_setup_000[<?php echo $auflage['auflage_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $auflage['auflage_id']; ?>">
        <input type="<?php echo $input; ?>" class="form-control" name="add_setup_001[<?php echo $auflage['auflage_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $auflage['auflage_name']; ?>">
        <?php foreach ($view_old_tcg as $tcg): ?>
            <input type="<?php echo $input; ?>" class="form-control" name="add_setup_00<?php echo $tcg['tcg_id'] + 1; ?>[<?php echo $auflage['auflage_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $auflage['auflage_' . $tcg['tcg_short'] . '']; ?>">
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
    </br>
<?php } ?>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Comment: And this one too
```
<?php foreach ($view_old_tcg as $tcg) { ?>
            <input type="<?php echo $input; ?>" class="form-control" name="add_setup_00<?php echo $tcg['tcg_id'] + 1; ?>[<?php echo $auflage['auflage_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $auflage['auflage_' . $tcg['tcg_short'] . '']; ?>">
        <?php } ?>
```